# How to quickly identify SSH private key file formats?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, private-key, pkcs

Triggered today by [Remote Desktop Manager,](https://remotedesktopmanager.com/) whose SSH Key Generator offered to save a private key in *OpenSSH* format, but then proceeded to store it in *PKCS#1 / OpenSSL* format, while using the same random `*.pri` file extension for two of the offered formats.

[image: save as]

I just wanted to connect to an AWS EC2 instance, but WinSCP, FileZilla and PuTTY all use different private key formats.

Feel free to offer more insight, this is just my current incomplete understanding.

Answer (score 23):

The file extension is often either random or not enough to identify the format.

Broad categories:

- [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) files with [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) data, encoded with [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding)
- PEM files with data encoded in some other format
- Non-PEM formats

PEM files wrap [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) between `-----BEGIN-----` and `-----END-----` "tags". They are also commonly used to contain both private key and SSL certificate (-chain). Use an [online ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js) to check the Base64 contents of a PEM file.

## PEM Files

**[PKCS#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) / OpenSSL**: id_rsa, *.pem, *.der, *.key, ...

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

PuTTY Key Generator calls this "OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format)" (?). The "SSLeay" or "traditional" format, according to [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47433/75384). Base64 starts with `MII...`. [ASN.1 content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.2). [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065304/differences-between-begin-rsa-private-key-and-begin-private-key).

**[PKCS#8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_8)**: *.pem, *.der, *.key, ...

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` or `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`

Base64 of the unencrypted variation starts with `MII...IBADAN`. ASN.1 content, basically PKCS#1 plus version info. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065304/differences-between-begin-rsa-private-key-and-begin-private-key).

**[OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH)**: *.??? (don't know what a typical file extension would be)

`-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`

PEM on the outside, but non-ASN.1 content. Apparently a [somewhat undocumented format](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format).

## Non-PEM Files

**[PuTTY Private Key](https://putty.org/)**: *.ppk

Content also contains human readable words identifying it as a putty private key.

**[PKCS#12 / PFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12)**: *.p12, *.pfx

PFX is a Microsoft format, later released in cleaned-up form as PKCS#12. The content is binary, and can contain not only a private key, but also an SSL certificate (-chain).

Comment: The OpenSSH format doesn't use DER, but it does use standard SSHv2 packet data types (e.g. `32-bit length, <...>` is exactly the standard format of a 'string' type in SSHv2 packets). So the documentation at [PROTOCOL.key](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.key) and [draft-miller-ssh-agent](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-miller-ssh-agent-02#section-4.2.1) should be sufficient, combined with data type definitions at [RFC 4251](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4251#section-5).

Comment: For OpenSSH 'new' format https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.key . Nit: PKCS12 can (and almost always does) contain _X.509v3/PKIX_ certs, which are used not only for SSL/TLS but also S/MIME, XMLdsig/enc, some code signing, PDF signing, and more. (But not SSH.)

Comment: Please do NOT use an online decoder for your private PEM files.  They are PRIVATE.